# A Hausdorff space which is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

It is said thet the set $A=\{(x,y): x>0, y\in\mathbb{R} \}\cup \{(0,0)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff but not locally compact. Can anyone tell how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $A$ such that $\overline{U}$ (closure in $A$) is compact.

Then it's easy to see that $U$ must contain a sequence of the form $(\frac 1n, p)$ for some $p >0$, for large enough $n$, say. And this sequence does not have a convergent subsequence in $\overline{U}$ (it converges to $(0,p) \notin A$ in $\Bbb R^2$ etc.). This would contradict compactness of $\overline{U}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the origin. You cannot find a compact neighborhood of $(0,0)$. To see that, imagine a ball in $A$ containing $(0,0)$. Then this ball is basically the right half of the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but missing the part of the boundary that lies on the y-axis (excluding the origin of course), which is not a compact set.

Comment: Ok. I thought of the same argument. But how does one show that the set is Hausdorff? Like if we take one of the points to be the origin in the definition of Hausdorff space.

Comment: just by using the definitions of Hausdorff space and the relatively open set, as well the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: in particular, it is easy to see that if $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space, then any subspace of $X$ is Hausdorff

Comment: to be more explicit, consider the origin and any other point of $A$, lets call it x. then consider the obviously disjoint open balls $B_1$, $B_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with same radius $r := \frac{\| x\|}{3} and centers the origin and $x$ respectively. then $B_1 \cap A$ and $B_2 \cap A$ are two disjoint neighborhoods in $A$, of the origin and $x$ respectively

Comment: to be more explicit, consider the origin and any other point of A, lets call it x. then consider the obviously disjoint open balls B1, B2 in R2, with same radius $r:=\frac{∥x∥}{3}$ and centers the origin and $x$ respectively.then $B_1 \cap A$ and $B_2 \cap A$ are two disjoint neighborhoods in $A$, of the origin and$x$ respectively.